# How do I know IP address of AWS API Gateway hosted on stage?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Actually I have database which has IP based restriction and now if I'm calling API using API Gateway Invoke URL, then got error because can't connect with database.
Question:
How do we know IP address of hosting server of API gateway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  It's a large pool of dynamic IP addresses.

You didn't mention a Lambda function in the mix, but that would be the only way that comes to mind that you could use to originate requests behind API Gateway with a static source address.  The Lambda function would need to be associated with subnets whose default route points to a NAT Gateway in a VPC.  The NAT Gateway always has a static IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually I'm adding resources to API and then add http method with Lambda Function.